# Prove $A_4$ acts on the set of edges of the tetrahedron T and find the stabilizer of $A_{4_{(1,2)}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

I'm trying to solve the following task:

[image]

I don't know how im supposed to go about this. How can the set of even permutations of 4 elements act on a 6-element set.

I understand it can permute the 4 points, and that reflects on the edge-set. But would that be acting on the Vertex set, and not the edge set? The edge set differences would change only as a consequence.

I'm really having difficulties with both a) and b). Please help me solve this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If it acts on the points, then if you imagine the whole tetrahedron rotating/reflecting, you also obtain an action on the edges.

Comment: I think @ElliotG has it right. The action on the vertices *induces* an action on the edges.

Comment: I agree with that but how could i prove it using the axioms for group actions

Comment: The action on vertices is clear, right? So the action on edges is also easy to notate. For $\sigma\in S^4$ and an edge $\{v_1,v_2\}$, set $\sigma(\{v_1,v_2\})=\{\sigma(v_1),\sigma(v_2)\}$, where $\sigma(v_i)$ denotes the action on vertices. That should be a good place to start from. (Sorry if this renders poorly; I’m on mobile.)